# There was a failure when processing annotations for application

Tags: annotations, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c

I have an application that is using jsf2,hibernate4,spring4 and i am using the annotations in all the project ,the project was working fine on the Tomcat server ,but a new requirement appear that i have to use weblogic application server so i have installed weblogic 12.1.3 cause i have read it supports web module 3.0 
,but when to deploy to weblogic i got this error

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application C:\EclipseWorkspace\TESTAPP\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 25, 2016 11:00:30 AM AST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "2242903179842832" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 25, 2016 11:00:30 AM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating distribute task for application "_auto_generated_ear_".> 
<Apr 25, 2016 11:00:30 AM AST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

my pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TESTAPP</groupId>
    <artifactId>TESTAPP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TESTAPP</name>


    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- JSF Version -->
        <jsf.version>2.2.10</jsf.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.178</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.5</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So did any one faces this before ,and can provide some help?
thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standards support by weblogic 12.1.3 does not match your definitions unfortunately. What I saw from a fast glimpse: 
You expect EE 7, but WL 12.1.3 only supports EE 6. 
You expect JSF 2.2, but WL 12.1.3 only supports 2.1.*

See here for the full list [What's New in Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES128)

Comment: thanks for the reply ,so what i have to change to make it work ?do i have to remove all the spring and the jsf annotations too? besides going to the old version ?

Comment: I don't think you have to remove everything, that would break the functionality, right? Change to the older version, then you should see some compile errors.