# Oracle ADF 12c : Desktopintegration Servlet DIRemoteServlet

Tags: java, oracle-adf, classnotfoundexception

Im trying to deploy my ADF web application, WebLogic started successfully but when I run the application server terminated and throw this exception :

I installed DesktopIntegration lib and I tested to export excel sheet and it works, but the more scare this is im not using this lib in this application.

```
    [09:58:49 AM] Deploying Application
<14-Apr-2019 09:59:01,145 o'clock CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application E:\Interface_Co\Projects\Malomatia\ADF\tools\jdev_java_122130\jdeveloper\jdev\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\o.j2ee\drs\hotel_db_v3\ViewControllerWebApp.war. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet> 
<14-Apr-2019 09:59:01,552 o'clock CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1032862977496400" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<14-Apr-2019 09:59:01,736 o'clock CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "hotel_db_v3".> 
<14-Apr-2019 09:59:01,737 o'clock CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.desktopintegration.servlet.DIRemoteServlet
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
[09:59:01 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[09:59:01 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[09:59:01 AM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application hotel_db_v3 due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[09:59:02 AM] Cancel requested
[Application hotel_db_v3 stopped and undeployed from IntegratedWebLogicServer]
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835218/there-was-a-failure-when-processing-annotations-for-application ?

Comment: This might be helpful - I am not close enough to tell: http://www.catgovind.com/adf/adf-error-deployment-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-adf-model-servlet-adfbindingfilter/